# How can we set user level customized environment variables in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have added different users in Jenkins by going through 
Manage Jenkins -->  Manage Users --> Create User

Now i have logged in to Jenkins using one of these users and want to have my own environment variables, so that no one else can access my environment variables?

I want to create below environment variables
svn_username=
svn_password=

Could you please help me if we can achieve this in Jenkins?

Thanks & regards,
Balakrishna K

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any plugins that will do this. The Build User Vars plugin will show you some variables about the user, but nothing you can define yourself.

If you only want credentials, then credentials CAN be set on a per-user basis. Just click on the Credentials link on the left menu while you are configuring a user.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thank you for your response. I tried doing it, but it is masking while i am accessing these values. 
My requirement with little clarity. 
1. We will be having some jenkin users.
2. We want to have 2 environment variables namely svn_user_name & svn_password. These vars values will be different for each user but vars names will be same. 
3. When i try to run the build job(which is common for all the users), i want to pass these env vars with my svn_u_name and pass values to the build script as arguments.
4. Inside the build script, it needs these 2 arguments for further processing.

Comment: They only mask in the console log. You can still use them and pass them around. You can even use something like environment{ SVN_USER=credentials{CRED_ID)} to put them into the environment and use them directly in shell scripts.